# Concatenate strings with punctuations

Tags: python

I want to concatenate strings who end with "," and ";" and stop when a string ends with "."

```py
string2 = "Hello World;"
string3 = "Hello World,"
string4 = "Hello Word."

my_list = [string2, string3, string4]

def concat_strings(my_list):

    N = len(my_list)

    for idx in range(0, N):

        text = my_list[idx]

        if text[-1:] != '.':

            text = text + my_list[idx + 1]

        else:

            print('False')

        my_list[idx] = text

    return my_list

my_list2 = concat_strings(my_list)
```

What I want is "`Hello World; Hello World, Hello World.`"

What I get is :

```
"Hello World;Hello World,"
"Hello World,Hello World."
"Hello World."
```

Comment: @MikeTung I tried to use a while loop to concatenate strings until the '.' but it's an infinite loop. I also tried to call the function (recursive method) but multiple errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution should cover different cases. Sometimes, the punctuation may appear at the beginning of the string or sometimes no punctuation exists in the string. There could be any random punctuation too. Another condition you specify is that you want to include the string with the '.' and stop iterating over further strings after that.

The following solution uses `punctuation` available in the `string` library:

```
string2 = "Hello World;"
string3 = "Hello World,"
string4 = "Hello World."
string5 = "Hello World"

my_list = [string2, string3, string4, string5]
punctuation_list = list(punctuation)
stop = '.'
from string import punctuation
l = [string for string in my_list for i in string if any([i in punctuation_list])]
l1 = []
for i in l:
    if i.endswith(stop):
        l1.append(i)
        break
    else:
        l1.append(i)

print(''.join(l1))
'Hello World;Hello World,Hello World.'
```

Comment: Yes but I want to stop the concatenation after '.' and with your example I have '!Hello World' after the '.'

Answer (score 1):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
s = [string2, string3, string4]    
print(" ".join([x + x if x.endswith(';') and x.endswith(',') else x for x in s]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Hello World; Hello World, Hello Word.
```

**EDIT**:

Since the sequence could be changed, Here is an approach using `set()`:

```
s = [string4, string3, string2]     # change the sequence to however you may

p = [x for x in s if x.endswith(';') or x.endswith(',')]

print(" ".join(p + list(set(s) - set(p))))
```

Comment: It doesn't do what is expected, just try with `s = ["Hello World;", "Hello World.", "Hello World,"] `, you'll see that it doesn't stop at the `.`. As `x.endswith(';') and x.endswith(',')` is always `False`, this code is just equivalent to `" ".join(s)`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ofcourse it does not. If you look at the question being asked again, *I want to concatenate strings who end with "," and ";" and stop when a string ends with "."* Which means, they are in the sequence `s = [string2, string3, string4]`. I could edit to an alternative though.

Comment: If the strings always were in sequence, with only the last one ending with '.', then there wouldn't be anything to do except concatenate all the strings, which would make the question meaningless - and the OP's code shows that he tried to stop concatenating when encountering a '.'

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Agreed, let me think it through!

Comment: With your last version, `s = ['a;', 'D.', 'b,', 'DD.', 'c;']`  gives `a; b, c; DD. D.`. It doesn't stop at the first dot, but takes all strings not ending with a dot, then adds the unique ones ending with a dot in random order.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it simple: just append to the output, stop appending when a string ends with a `'.'`

```
data = ["Hello World;", "Hello World.", "Hello World,"]    

out = []
for s in data:
    out.append(s)
    if s.endswith('.'):
        break
print(' '.join(out))
```

Output:

```
Hello World; Hello World.
```